# VBA table columns/rows converting and changing currency

Tags: vba

I have got an assignment in VBA where I have to convert an existing table's rows to colums, but I only have to show two rows from the table and all that has to be done with the help of an ActiveX control button. I also have to change the table cells values to Euros and back to Estonian Kroons with the help of a button. Thirdly, I have to find a value and the price of it according to the new table.

I have already written the code as much as I could, but it does not work correctly. There are a few problems: a)firstly, after pressing the solving button it does not give all the values in the new table, b)secondly, when I try to use the currency changing buttons Euros/Kroons, it multiplies my values infinitely and thirdly I do not get a right answer when I have to find the cheapest SMS package name and the price of it.

I guess my explanation was very messy, so I am adding the Excel file that can be seen here: http://www.2shared.com/file/awEG5hf-/KT_online.html

The code is really long, so I don't want to add it here, but the image from the assignment looks like this: [image] that image shows the correct solution of the assignment.

I really, really appreciate it if someone could find time to help me. A huge thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following subs

SHEET1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Sheet1.Range("E6").Value = "Prices in Euros" Or Sheet1.Range("E6").Value = ""    Then eek
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If Sheet1.Range("E6").Value = "Prices in Kroons" Or Sheet1.Range("E6").Value = "" Then eur
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    lahenda
End Sub
```

MODULE1

```
Sub lahenda()

With Sheet1
    .Range("B8:B16,F8:F16").Copy
    .Range("B18:J19").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
    .Range("C23").Formula = "=MIN(H9:H16)"
    .Range("C24").Formula = "=INDEX(B9:B16,MATCH(minhind,H9:H16,0),1)"
End With

End Sub
```

MODULE2

```
Sub eur()
    Dim prk As Range, hinnad As Range, koht1
    Dim n, m
    Set prk = Range("alg").CurrentRegion
    n = prk.Rows.Count - 1
    m = prk.Columns.Count - 1
    Set hinnad = prk.Offset(1, 1).Resize(n, m)

    Set koht1 = prk.Cells(2, 2)

    ReDim a(1 To n, 1 To m), paketid(1 To n), naitajad(1 To m)
    ReDim veerg(1 To n), rida(1 To m)
    ReDim b(1 To n, 1 To m)

    a = hinnad

    kurss = Range("kurss")
    tee_tabel a(), n, m, b(), kurss
    tabel_lehele b(), n, m, koht1
 Sheet1.Range("E6").Value = "Prices in Euros"
End Sub
```

MODULE3

```
Sub eek()
    Dim prk As Range, hinnad As Range, koht1 As Range
    Dim n, m
    Set prk = Range("alg").CurrentRegion
    n = prk.Rows.Count - 1
    m = prk.Columns.Count - 1
    Set hinnad = prk.Offset(1, 1).Resize(n, m)

    Set koht1 = prk.Cells(2, 2)

    ReDim a(1 To n, 1 To m), paketid(1 To n), naitajad(1 To m)
    ReDim veerg(1 To n), rida(1 To m)
    ReDim b(1 To n, 1 To m)

    a = hinnad

    kurss = Range("kurss")
    tee_tabel a(), n, m, b(), kurss
    tabel_lehele b(), n, m, koht1
 Sheet1.Range("E6").Value = "Prices in Kroons"
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. i will check this solution today and give a feedback!